# Exchange data from C++ to QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

And sorry about the vague title, i don't know how to express it better, so pardon me.

I got a class to store data, inherit from QObject, and a loginSignal

```
class UserData : public QObject {
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   Q_INVOKABLE QString login(const QString p_user, const QString p_password, const bool p_remember);
   UserData(QObject* parent = 0);
   signals:
      void userLogin();
};
```

Register class to QML

```
qmlRegisterType<UserData>("UserData",1,0,"UserData");
```

Connect to a QML Element

```
ApplicationWindow {
   UserData {
      id:userData
   }
   Rectangle {
      Connections {
         target: userData
         onUserLogin : {
            doSomething()
         }
      }
   }
}
```

However if i call emit(userLogin()) signal inside login() function, nothing happend in QML

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine(QUrl("qrc:///mainControl.qml"));
    QQmlContext* context = engine.rootContext();

    UserData userData;
    context->setContextProperty("userData",&userData);

        userData.login(user, pass, true);

    return app.exec();
}
```

Maybe QML Component hasn't complete finished yet?
And thank for dropping by

Edit : Look like i accident create a second instance in QML, and use it. Everything working fine now :D

Comment: Why are you creating an instance in QML _and_ creating another in C++ for a context property?

Comment: Eh, i never thought of it until you point it out. 
So i instead of 
UserData {
      id:userData
   }

I should make it as a component property?

Comment: It depends on what you actually need. Do you need it to be on the C++ side, or maybe you can do with instantiating it in QML? Do you know what you need? :) Or maybe you are just playing around?

Comment: UserData class is a bridge between QML and C++, it handle the data, connect to database... then parse data to QML to display.
So i guess, i need it on C++ side?

Comment: Well, not necessarily - remember, `UserData` is still a C++ class, so you have access to C++ in its implementation, you can implement all data and database functionality and port it so that it can be used from the QML side, and instantiate it in QML. In this case you just need to interface it to QML better.

Comment: Then, let's get straight to the point
From QML side, i just want to call methods in UserData class to collect data, and store them in it own properties (for example Q_Property user, password)  So QML can get , and display them.

Comment: Sounds like you don't really need `UserData` instantiated in C++ then, just implement what you need as properties or slots returning the data, and maybe a good idea to implement a state and corresponding enums to make it more elegant to track it, you know like `Disconnected, Connecting, Connected, Error`

Comment: Ah,i understand, thank a lots for helping me :D